# How does Prime31 android IAP plugin server side manual Server Verification？

Tags: android, plugins, in-app-purchase, prime31

Here is my thought：
Is the work flow right for server side verification for google iab plugin in-app billing?

1. close autoverify in unity3d
2. java method handleActivityResult call the onIabPurchaseCompleteAwaitingVerification
3.onIabPurchaseCompleteAwaitingVerification calls the method in unity3d GoogleIABManager.purchaseCompleteAwaitingVerification(string json) 
4. unity post the message to my own game server for verifiaction.
5.after server verified, send the result to unity.
6.Here I add my own method in GoogleIABManager

```
public static void ManualVerifyResult(int result, string json){ if(purchaseSucceededEvent!=null && result ==1}{purchaseSucceededEvent.fire(new GooglePurchase(json.directoryFromJson())); else if (purchaseFailedEvent！= null && result== 0){ purchaseFailedEvent(dict["result"].toString(), responseString)}}
```

7.then the raised purchaseSuccessEvent send message to my gameserver and add item to database, the raised purchaseFailedEvent show the error message on UI?